# How do I find out that what is added in the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a piece of code which compares two dictionaries.

```
if dict1 != dict2:
   pass
```

Dict2 is actually copy of dict1 and I wanna know what extra is added to dict2. I want the difference in another dictionary.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach for changes to the keys and/or changes to the values -

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':-3, 'd':4}

if dict1!=dict2:
    diff = dict(dict2.items()-dict1.items())
    print(diff)
else:
    print('They are the same!')
```

```
{'d': 4, 'c': -3}
```